# Do there exist energy-minimizing immersions?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, harmonic-functions, variational-analysis

Let $M,N$ be $d$-dimensional connected oriented Riemannian manifolds, possibly with boundary, $M$ compact. Let $E_d:C^{\infty}(M,N) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the $d$-energy, i.e.

$$ E_d(f)=\int_M |df|^d \text{Vol}_M.$$

> Set $E_{M,N}=\inf \{ E_d(f) \, | \,\, f \in C^{\infty}(M,N) \text{ is an immersion} \}$, and suppose that $E_{M,N} >0$.
>
> Does $E_{M,N}$ always obtained? i.e. does there exist an immersion with minimal energy? (I am assuming there exist at least one immersion from $M$ to $N$.  )

I am specifically considering the $d$-energy between $d$-manifolds, and not the $2$-energy; for the $2$-energy the answer can be negative; it is known that

$$\inf_{f \in \text{Diff}(\mathbb{S}^n) }  E_2(f) =0$$ when $n >2$,
but there is no immersion with zero $2$-energy.

However, the identity map $\text{Id}_{M^d}$ has minimal $d$-energy among all diffeomorphisms. (So, in particular, for any simply-connected and closed $M$, we have $E_{M,M}=E_d(\text{Id}_{M})$ as any immersion is a diffeomorphism).

Comment: So $|df|$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm $\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(df^*df)}$? I don't think that definition is so common as to go unsaid.

Comment: Yes it is. Maybe I should add this comment. (It is rather common in the literature on harmonic maps, I think).

Comment: I'm not especially familiar with differential geometry, so I may be misunderstanding something here, but if $M=N=[0,1]$, cannot you get arbitrarilily small positive energy by choosing immersion $x\mapsto cx$ for $c\searrow 0$? But no immersion can have zero energy.

Comment: @Litho Hmmm... you are absolutely right. I forgot to add the requirement that the infimum energy is greater than zero (which was the case I was more interested in). I think that now we might have a non-trivial question... thank you for your observation.

Comment: Then you would probably also want to add that $M$ is connected. Otherwise, choosing $M=N$ to be the union of $S^1$ and a closed interval gives a simple example where the minimal energy is non-zero, but still not achievable.

Comment: Actually, it's better to add that $N$ is connected as well, or you could take $M=S^1$ and $N$ as the union of countably many circles with radii $1+1/n$.

Comment: Thank you again; Indeed, your comments make it clear that it is not trivial to formulate a precise (and interesting) question here. Let's wait and see what happens now...

Comment: This is false already for $d=1$ and $N$ a surface of revolution. I think, you should assume that $N$ is compact.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am not sure what exactly do you mean; I assumed that $\dim M=\dim N=d$ (so "$d=1$" and $N$ being a surface of revolution seems incompatible to me). However, I am interested to hear about the example you have in mind, even if it doesn't fit strictly into the setting of the question. Can you describe it a bit more? (perhaps in an answer, if there is no place in the comments). Anyway, I think that I would be happy to assume that $N$ is compact, or perhaps $N=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh, I missed the assumption that manifolds have the same dimension. But, still, if you do not assume compactness of $N$ and allow $M$ to have boundary, there is an example when both are surfaces (topologically, $M$ is a compact annulus and $N$ is a noncompact one).

Comment: @MoisheKohan If I understand correctly what you mean, this is again a case where the infimum energy is 0, which the OP wants to exclude. If $M$ is an annulus, it can be immersed into an arbitrarily small neighbourhood on any 2-dimensional $N$, and one can get arbitrarily small positive energy this way.

Comment: @Litho: You are right, I was thinking about homotopically nontrivial maps. I posted an answer with a 4-dimensional version of this example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a 4-dimensional counter-example where you allow $M$ to have boundary. The motivating 2-dimensional version of this construction is as follows:

Take $N$ which is the surface of revolution obtained by rotating the graph of $y=e^x + 0.5$ around the $x$-axis in $R^3$ (with the induced Riemannian metric). Notice that the infimum of lengths of embedded homotopically nontrivial loops on $N$ is $2\pi$ and it is not realized by any loop. Take $M$ which is the product annulus $S^1\times [0,1]$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle. Then the infimum of 2-energies of homotopically nontrivial maps $M\to N$ equals the area of $M$ but it is not achieved. As @Litho correctly noted, nevertheless $E(M,N)=0$ since you can take homotopically trivial embeddings. (Nevertheless, this is an example if you require immersions to be homotopically nontrivial. )

Similarly, if you consider connected oriented 3-manifolds and $M$ has nonempty boundary then $E(M,N)=0$ (since one can immerse every such $M$ in $R^3$).

To get the actual example, we go one dimension up. Let $M$ be a simply-connected smooth compact **non-spin** oriented 4-manifold with boundary. Then $M$ does not admit immersions in $R^4$.

For concreteness I will take $M$ to the complement to a 4-ball in $CP^2$. Then $M$ has structure of a disk bundle over $S^2$ 
(with the Euler number 1).  I will equip $M$ with a Riemannian metric such that there is a fibration $M\to S^2$ 
over the round 2-sphere (of the unit radius) which is a submetry.  I think (but I did not check this), the least 4-energy map from $M$ to such 
$S^2$ is given by the projection $p$, in which case, $E(M, S^2)=  Vol(M)$.

Now, take a 4-manifold $N$ which is diffeomorphic to an infinite connected sum of $CP^2$'s. One needs to choose a suitable Riemannian metric on $N$ such that the $k$th $CP^1$ admits a neighborhood isometric to a rescaled (by $\lambda_k>1$) version of the above example with $\lambda_k$ converging to $1$ as $k\to \infty$.

We then have a sequence of immersions $f_k: M\to N$ whose 4-energies converge to $Vol(M)$ from above (without ever reaching it). One still needs to check that there are no immersions of smaller 4-energy. I do not see any possible candidates but proving this would require much more work that I can afford.

The real question, I think, is about maps between closed manifolds which then are necessarily finite covering maps. 
A paper to read is

B. White, [Homotopy classes in Sobolev spaces and the existence of energy minimizing maps](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485890515), Acta Math. 160 (1988), 1-17.

Or you  can simply email Brian (he is at Stanford): He is a very nice guy and will help if he can.